# Question about loading collectionView cell repeatedly in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to load collectionView Cell repeatedly.

I want to make a dynamic cell, and when 20 cells are loaded, I want to make 40 cells by loading 20 underneath again.

```
API.requestBookCategory(bookCategory: 9, bookAddPoint: 0, completionHandler: handleBooksCategory(books:error:))
```

```
func handleBooksCategory(books: Books?, error: Error?) {
        self.booksCategory = books
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

This code retrieves information from 20 books in `bookCategory` 9.
When importing 1 to 20 book information, insert `bookAddPoint` 0.

After that, we insert book information into the `bookCatagory` variable and use `bookCategory` to display the book information data in the cell.

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return booksCategory?.books.count ?? 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView
            .dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MainBookCell", for: indexPath) as! MainBookCell

        func handleImageResponse() {
            guard let imageURL = URL(string: booksCategory?.books[indexPath.row].bookImage ?? "") else {
                return
            }

            API.requestImageFile(url: imageURL, completionHandler: handleImageFileResponse(image:error:))
        }

        func handleImageFileResponse(image: UIImage?, error: Error?) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.bookImageView.image = image
            }
        }

        cell.bookTitleLabel.text = booksCategory?.books[indexPath.row].bookTitle
        cell.bookWriterLabel.text = booksCategory?.books[indexPath.row].authorName
        handleImageResponse()

        return cell
    }
}
```

I go through the process up to here, and a cell displaying 20 book information is created.

If a cell showing the 20th book information is created,

`API.requestBookCategory (bookCategory: 9, bookAddPoint: 20, completionHandler: handleBooksCategory (books: error :))`

I want to run a code that modifies `bookAddPoint` from 0 to 20, like the code above, to create a cell that displays the 21st to 40th book information. What should I do?

Comment: I believe you want to create something like this article https://www.raywenderlich.com/5786-uitableview-infinite-scrolling-tutorial. Go through this post.. see how they call apis, for "load more" feature.. and then maybe, you can refine your question and ask if there is any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in viewControoller create a variables

```
var bookAddPoint = 0
var pageLength = 20

func callNextPageData(){
  bookAddPoint =  booksCategory?.books.count + 1
  API.requestBookCategory(bookCategory: 9, bookAddPoint: bookAddPoint, completionHandler: handleBooksCategory(books:error:))
  }
```

**change**

```
func handleBooksCategory(books: Books?, error: Error?) {
    for book in books{
self.booksCategory.appen(book)
}
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**Change** cellforItem

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView
        .dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MainBookCell", for: indexPath) as! MainBookCell

    func handleImageResponse() {
        guard let imageURL = URL(string: booksCategory?.books[indexPath.row].bookImage ?? "") else {
            return
        }

        API.requestImageFile(url: imageURL, completionHandler: handleImageFileResponse(image:error:))
    }

    func handleImageFileResponse(image: UIImage?, error: Error?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.bookImageView.image = image
        }
    }

    cell.bookTitleLabel.text = booksCategory?.books[indexPath.row].bookTitle
    cell.bookWriterLabel.text = booksCategory?.books[indexPath.row].authorName
    handleImageResponse()
   if indexPath.row == self.booksCategory.count-3 // it will load records before you reach end point automatically you can increase or decrease number
 {
       callNextPageData()
}

    return cell
}
```

**NOTE:** if you want to do this on load more button just call callNextPageData() in button action or in tableView footer actions.

Comment: UI Hassan 
ThankYou!

Comment: But let me ask you one more question.
```
if indexPath.row == self.booksCategory.count-3 // it will load records before you reach end point you can increase or decrease number
  {
        callNextPageData ()
}
```
When this code is ```indexPath.row == self.booksCategory.count-3```, can it be called only once?

Comment: Yes it can be called only once

Comment: create a bool onceRefreshed=false  
  if indexPath.row == self.booksCategory.count-3 && !onceRefreshed // it will load records before you reach end point automatically you can increase or decrease number
 {
        onceRefreshed=true
       callNextPageData()
}